# Trying to make SQL Profiler with TraceServer() C#

Tags: c#-4.0

When debug program in line:

```
    reader.InitializeAsReader(ci, @"D:\trace2\trace3.trc");
```

Exception: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\pfclnt.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I try to add references from sql 2012 but still get the error

```
        TraceServer reader = new TraceServer();

        ConnectionInfoBase ci = new SqlConnectionInfo();
        (ci as SqlConnectionInfo).ServerName = "localhost";

        ((SqlConnectionInfo)ci).UseIntegratedSecurity = true;

            reader.InitializeAsReader(ci, @"D:\trace2\trace3.trc");

            int eventNumber = 0;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.Write("{0}\n", reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                eventNumber++;
                if (eventNumber == 10) break;
            }
```